# How to populate a Collection with a function then call the collection to fill a combo box in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA, and I would like to fill a collection with a range of cells from a worksheet. I later will want to add and subtract line items, so I need it to dynamically include all rows I need in columns 1, 2, and 3. I then need to call the function that fills the collection to fill some different combo boxes but I only want to fill the combo box with the first two columns of the collection. I would like the first column to be the key for each line item in the collection.

I have read a good bit online but I am repeatedly getting the Runtime error 91: object variable or with block variable not set. In addition I seem to be having trouble actually calling the collection function in my userform sub. This may have something to do with the structure of my code but I cannot figure out what. This may be basic but I have been trying to figure it out for quite a while and have not been able to.

```
Dim cCodes As Collection
Function getCodes() As Collection

Set cCodes = New Collection
Dim rRange As Range
Dim rRow As Range
Set getCodes = New Collection
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate

Let rRange = Range("A4:C4")
Let rRow = Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
For Each rRange In rRow
 cCodes.Add rRange.Cells(0, 0), rRange.Cells(0, 1), rRange.Cells(0, 2), 
  Key:=rRange.Cells(0, 1)
 Let rRange = rRange.Offset(1, 0)

 Next rRange

Set getCodes = cCodes


End Function







Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 dateIn.Value = Now                                         
 dateIn = Format(dateIn.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    sundayDate.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 24) 

Dim cCodes As Collection
Set cCodes = getCodes


With UserForm1
  CostCode1.List = cCodes                            
  CostCode2.List = cCodes
  CostCode3.List = cCodes
  CostCode4.List = cCodes
  CostCode5.List = cCodes
  CostCode6.List = cCodes
    End With
   ......more userform code

End Sub
```

I want it to run smoothly, for the collection to be global and always be updated with all line items in the columns specified (stop at first empty row). I will also want to use this collection in other places so need to be able to call it. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a global variable. It is a bad practice and prone to errors. Instead I'd call a `Sub` to build the collection and use it later like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub getCodes(cCodes As Collection)

    Set cCodes = New Collection
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Set getCodes = New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    Let rRange = Range("A4:C4")
    Let rRow = Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
    For Each rRange In rRow
        cCodes.Add rRange.Cells(0, 0), rRange.Cells(0, 1), rRange.Cells(0, 2), Key:=rRange.Cells(0, 1)
        Let rRange = rRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Next rRange

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim cCodes As Collection
    dateIn.Value = Now
    dateIn = Format(dateIn.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    sundayDate.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 24)

    getCodes cCodes

    With UserForm1
        CostCode1.List = cCodes
        CostCode2.List = cCodes
        CostCode3.List = cCodes
        CostCode4.List = cCodes
        CostCode5.List = cCodes
        CostCode6.List = cCodes
    End With
       ......more userform code
End Sub
```

So you declare only **once** your variable on the main sub, I think in your example that's `UserForm_Initalize` once you declare it there, you can pass `cCodes` to `getCodes` like this: `getCodes cCodes` and the procedure will build your collection ready to be used on the main procedure or the ones to come if used the same way.

Another tip is to use `Option Explicit` which will force you to declare all your variables and your code will be better built.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I tried that and it seems to be having trouble with the way that I filled the collection, It is giving me error that the "named argument '.Cells' is already being used" inside of the collection sub. My code is the same as what you have up there. I was going to just do a new .Add for each item however I want them to be line items like in the spreadsheet and thus populate a 2d array if that makes sense

Comment: Can't help you on that note... I just copied your code but changed it only on the function/sub and declarations, nothing else. Anyway, I think you can only add one Key/Value and you are adding 4 items: `cCodes.Add rRange.Cells(0, 0), rRange.Cells(0, 1), rRange.Cells(0, 2), 
  Key:=rRange.Cells(0, 1)` I think you intend to concatenate some cells? that would be `cCodes.Add rRange.Cells(0, 0) & rRange.Cells(0, 1) & rRange.Cells(0, 2), rRange.Cells(0, 1)` @ChrisLafky

Comment: Why use a `Sub` when you can use a `Function` and return the Collection?

Comment: Also, fully qualify references to ranges and don't rely on defaults (`.Value`).

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer Dictionaries over Collections.  They both server functionally the same purpose, but I find Dictionaries offer advantages in terms of performance and ease of use.  That being said, I think something like this is what you're looking for.  This is, admittedly, fairly advanced so I commented the code to help with following what it's doing:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim hCodes As Object
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim aCols As Variant

    'This is the sheet that contains the data you wanted to get the codes from
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'This is the range containing the codes on that sheet
    Set rData = ws.Range("A4:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Create the dictionary object
    Set hCodes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Specify the columns you want to use for the comboboxes (1 is the first column, 2 is the second column, etc.)
    'It doesn't have to be consecutive, if you want 1st and 3rd columns for example you could specify Array(1, 3)
    aCols = Array(1, 2)

    'Populate the dictionary using the GetCodes function (see below)
    Set hCodes = GetCodes(rData, 2) 'First argument is the range to pull the codes from, the second argument is the column that contains the keys

    'Loop through each key in the populated dictionary
    For Each vKey In hCodes.Keys
        'Populate the correct combobox based on the key (these are examples, change to what your actual keys and comboboxes will be)
        'See below for the PopulateList function;
        '    first argument is the listbox that should be populated
        '    second argument is the full array of values that the list will be populated from
        '    third argument is the list of column numbers that will be used to pull from the provided array values
        Select Case vKey
            Case "a":   PopulateList Me.ComboBox1, hCodes(vKey), aCols
            Case "b":   PopulateList Me.ComboBox2, hCodes(vKey), aCols
            Case "c":   PopulateList Me.ComboBox3, hCodes(vKey), aCols
            Case "d":   PopulateList Me.ComboBox4, hCodes(vKey), aCols
            Case "e":   PopulateList Me.ComboBox5, hCodes(vKey), aCols
            Case "f":   PopulateList Me.ComboBox6, hCodes(vKey), aCols
        End Select
    Next vKey

End Sub

Private Function GetCodes(ByVal arg_rData As Range, Optional ByVal arg_lKeyCol As Long = 1) As Object

    'Verify the range provided and key column provided are valid
    If arg_rData.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid range provided: " & arg_rData.Address & Chr(10) & "Must be a contiguous range"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf arg_rData.Columns.Count < arg_lKeyCol Or arg_lKeyCol < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Key Column must be >= 1 and <= Provided range's column count"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim hResult As Object
    Dim hIndices As Object
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim aTemp() As Variant
    Dim ixNew As Long
    Dim ixData As Long
    Dim ixCol As Long

    'Prepare the data array
    If arg_rData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aData(1, 1) = arg_rData.Value
    Else
        aData = arg_rData.Value
    End If

    'Prepare the result dictionary, and use an Indices dictionary to keep track of where data should be loaded in it
    Set hResult = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set hIndices = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Loop through each row of the provided data range (we loaded it into the data array earlier)
    For ixData = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
        'Check if the key already exists
        If hResult.Exists(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)) Then
            'Key already exists, update the index so we know which row to populate to in the results
            hIndices(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)) = hIndices(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)) + 1
        Else
            'Key does not exist, prepare a result array for it in the Results dictionary and set the Index to 1
            ReDim aTemp(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(arg_rData.Columns(arg_lKeyCol), aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)), 1 To UBound(aData, 2))
            hResult(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)) = aTemp
            hIndices(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)) = 1
        End If

        'Clear the temp array and assign it to the current key's array
        Erase aTemp
        aTemp = hResult(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol))

        'Loop through each column in the data array
        For ixCol = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
            'Populate the temp array with the current value from the data array
            aTemp(hIndices(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)), ixCol) = aData(ixData, ixCol)
        Next ixCol

        'Set the appropriate Key of the Results dictionary to the temp array
        hResult(aData(ixData, arg_lKeyCol)) = aTemp
    Next ixData

    'Set the function's output the Results dictionary
    Set GetCodes = hResult

End Function

Private Sub PopulateList(ByVal arg_cComboBox As Control, ByVal arg_aData As Variant, ByVal arg_aColNums As Variant)

    Dim aList As Variant
    Dim vCol As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    'Prepare the list array
    ReDim aList(LBound(arg_aData, 1) To UBound(arg_aData, 1), 1 To UBound(arg_aColNums) - LBound(arg_aColNums) + 1)

    'Loop through each row of the provided data array
    For i = LBound(arg_aData, 1) To UBound(arg_aData, 1)
        j = 0
        'Loop through only the column numbers provided
        For Each vCol In arg_aColNums
            'Populate the list array with the correct item from the data array
            j = j + 1
            aList(i, j) = arg_aData(i, vCol)
        Next vCol
    Next i

    'Clear previous list, set the column count, and set the list to the now populated list array
    With arg_cComboBox
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = UBound(aList, 2)
        .List = aList
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but you can fill a combobox with an array:

```
Option Explicit
Function getCodes() as Variant ' intent is to return an array.
Dim rRange As Range
    Let rRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:C4") ' fully qualified.
    Let rRange = Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
    getCodes = rRange.Value ' return a 2D array that is three columns wide. 
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    dateIn.Value = Now
    dateIn = Format(dateIn.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    sundayDate.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 24)

    With UserForm1
        CostCode1.List = getCodes
        CostCode2.List = getCodes
        CostCode3.List = getCodes
        CostCode4.List = getCodes
        CostCode5.List = getCodes
        CostCode6.List = getCodes
    End With
       ......more userform code
End Sub
```

The use of a function instead of rolling those few lines into the main code will help future extension (e.g. adding parameters to the function to change the range where the codes are stored).